# VB.Net Multithreaded SerialPort

Tags: vb.net

,Im new with serialport programming. Is there any way to pass SerialPort(ex. .name, COM, etc..) properties in UI Thread in multithreaded application?

What I want is similar in the code below but set my properties as variables. For example(property=.name, property = .text). So that i can return it to the UI thread by calling **object.property**

```
Public Delegate Sub SetTextCallback(ByVal control As Control, ByVal text As String)
Public Sub SetText(ByVal control As Control, ByVal text As String)
    If control.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf SetText)
        frmMain.Invoke(d, New Object() {control, text})
    Else
        control.Text = text
    End If
End Sub
```

I want is something like this (there's equivalent snippet in c#.Net but I can't do it in VB.NET):

```
Public Delegate Sub SetTextCallback(ByVal control As Control, ByVal prop as property, ByVal text As String)
Public Sub SetText(ByVal control As Control, byVal prop as property, ByVal text As String)
    If control.InvokeRequired Then
       Dim d As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf SetText)
       frmMain.Invoke(d, New Object() {control, prop, text})
    Else
        control.prop = text
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Have you tried simply checking `InvokeRequired`?  Leave the serial stuff alone... let it run on its own thread.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Brad. I use invokeRequired But my problem is how to set the properties like the 2nd code... Sorry im  noob in multithreading...

Comment: I really don't follow what you are asking, sorry.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973631/system-io-ports-serialport-and-multithreading

Comment: @Jed did you get around to solving this?

Comment: @Rachael yeah I think. I can't recall now, its been 3 years already. Please check Micah's comment.