# C# forms app serialport multi-write without proper read

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, serial-port

I am using serialport in forms. My pc is linked with a external device through serialport.
I try to multi-write a sequence of data into the device with feedback read.
When I write the data one by one through mouse click, everything is good. But when I try to write-wait-read-write-wait-read.... in one thread. The feedback read comes back in a cluster of data at the end of the write instead of after every write.
my code looks like this

void button click write and read

{

serialport.write

wait

read

write

wait

read

...

}

I tried to invoke read function in the function and multi-thread read. But it doesn't seem to work. I guess the thread processes the main loop before processes all the reads functions.
My idea to fix this is to tail write function to the read function.
Anyone knows how the thread prioritizes function? Or a better idea to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Please add real code. And: how do you open and configure the serial port?

Comment: This page may be helpful. [SMC: The State Machine Compiler](http://smc.sourceforge.net/) Why don't you use this tool to create and incorporate the processing and state transitions required for your program?

Comment: @OneNoobPlayer, based on my research, you can follow the link[System.IO.Ports.SerialPort and Multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973631/system-io-ports-serialport-and-multithreading) to know how to use the serialport in the mutithreading.

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT Make a buffer large enough to print everything out at the end seems better